# T-SQL: How ensure that records with parents are ordered correctly for tree creation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tree

I am creating a tree structure out of records from a table. The table has an id column, and a parent id column, so naturally each record is placed until its parent. However, for this to happen, the parent must come before the children, otherwise the program obviously won't know where to put it. However, I'm not sure to do this ordering. At first I was sorting by parent id but obviously that won't work for something like the below:

```
ID | Parent ID
--------------
1  | 0
2  | 0
3  | 4
4  | 1
5  | 3
```

The goal is to create something like:

```
1
 - 4
   - 3
     - 5
2
```

But when sorted by parent id, it will be

```
ID | Parent ID
--------------
1  | 0
2  | 0
4  | 1
5  | 3
3  | 4
```

And the program will fail when trying to place node 5 because it can't find node 3 in the tree.

Comment: I'm really not following your question...  can you try explaining a bit more?

Comment: @Siyual I'm not really sure what I need to explain. I added an illustration of the goal. The problem is how to get the table sorted in the right order so that nodes are not created before their parents.

Comment: I'm not sure if tsql has anything fancy for this, but I believe you'll have to use recursion and temp tables/vars for this. I assume that you're selecting these results to return to a piece of software you're writing? If that's the case, this type of sorting is better suited to programming languages.

Comment: You are asking the equivalent of "how can I have my cake and eat it too"? This is why using DB id values as data points is a bad practice. What is an example of your expected output?

Comment: @JacobH Can you explain what I should be doing?

Comment: How will you place ID 3 in your tree if you need to create ID 4 first?

Comment: @JacobH I don't follow. It'll be placed first because the rows would be sorted as (just listing the ids): 1 2 4 3 5 so everything would be created before it's children.

Comment: @JacobH I'm curious about what the OP should be doing differently with the table design as well. It looks like regular old normalization.  ID is the pkey, and Parent ID would be the fkey.

Comment: I think Jacob is asking how the original table got populated with ID 3 having ParentID 4, when presumably ID 3 had to be added to the table before ID 4 existed.  It doesn't break any rules per se, now that it exists, but it is strange.

Comment: @TabAlleman Well with my actual data, the reason is that each record represents a menu which can be a child of other menus or a parent of menus. The menus can be configured, and it was while trying out the ability to configure the menus that this first came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a recursive CTE using levels that does what you want. Notice the use of REPLICATE to help format your output string based on the level:

```
declare @t table (id int, parent_id int)
insert into @t values (1, 0)
insert into @t values (2, 0)
insert into @t values (3, 4)
insert into @t values (4, 1)
insert into @t values (5, 3)

;with cte as
(
    select id, 0 as level, id as top_parent
    from @t
    where parent_id = 0
    union all
    select t.id, cte.level + 1, cte.top_parent
    from @t t
    inner join cte on t.parent_id = cte.id
)
select case when level = 0 then '' else REPLICATE(' ', level * 2 - 1) + '- ' end + cast(id as varchar(3)) from cte
order by top_parent, level
```

Yields:

```
1
 - 4
   - 3
     - 5
2
```

Here's the output from the CTE directly before building the output table. Note the top_parent column, which just passes the top level node all the way down the recursive chain - then you can order by top_parent and level:

```
id   level  top_parent
1    0      1
2    0      2
4    1      1
3    2      1
5    3      1
```

Answer (score 2):

In your recursive CTE, you need to keep track of the "Level" of each row (the trunk query has Level=0, and the recursive query has Level=Level+1), and you need to also keep track of the ID of the Level 0 ancestor (IDs 1,4,3 & 5 all have "1" for their Level 0 ancestor).

Then you `order by` [Level 0 Ancestor], Level, ID